# Starting an ASP.NET Core web project with API and razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, razor

I am a beginner in web development and I want to start a new ASP.NET Core project and I have some questions regarding the structure of the project and what is the best practice. So, my goal is to make a website using razor pages and web API all together. I thought about 2 options:

1. To make different projects for the API and for the razor pages and between them to make a C# library that has an API Helper which sends the HTTP requests to the API project.
2. To put the API and the razor pages in the same project. I think this option is much simpler but I have some concerns. How to call the API? (I saw that you can use jQuery or in the same way I can make an API Helper class). If I use jQuery for API call can I do the validation in C# before jQuery send the data to the API?

Another thing I want to ask is should I use Identity for authentication? I don`t want default pages and tables in my database when I do the migration. I want to customize them. I know that I can modify the Identity classes and pages if I scaffold them but I want to do it manually. I also know that making such an authentication system could be challenging but I want to learn how to do it.
To sum up, I am curious to know how are ASP.NET CORE web projects structured in development and I want to know some best practices to do all these things. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's **jQuery** - not "JQUERRY" - one "r" is **quite** enough - and it's not all uppercase.....

Answer (score 1):

I think you maybe misunderstand how razor pages works. Its a purely server-side rendering system. The client requests a page from the server, and the razor pages renders the whole page and sends the resulting HTML, CSS, JS to the client browser. This means you dont need to think of an API as a separate piece really. Unless you want to make it more complicated, a Razor Pages website will be a single project, where each page has two files, a View (.cshtml) file which combines c# and html to build the web page, and a backing .cs file which handles the routing and assembling of data to provide to the view, along with handling authentication etc.

As for authentication, I recommend you go with Identity if you plan on actually deploying this live, rolling your own authentication system out is difficult and error prone, and Identity is easy to customize to your particular needs, while also giving a good and secure starting point.

Comment: Tony Pacheco, thanks for your reply. Yes I know how razor pages work but I want also an API because it gives me the possibility to make lets say a mobile app for the website. I should have mentioned this at the beginning. I think you are right, I`ll stick with identity.